# How does Observables work in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am trying to wrap my head around how observables work in Angular 2 instead of just using them as a pattern. If I create a basic observable like below, I can call the subscribe method on the source variable which exists as a result of creating the observable and assigning it to the source variable.

```
let numbers = [19, 38, 57];
let source = Observable.from(numbers);

source.subscribe(
  value => console.log(`value: ${value}`),
  error => console.log(`error: ${error}`),
  () => console.log('complete')
);
```

In Angular 2 I have the following code:

***Component:***

```
private getDevicesByUserId(): void {
  this.devicesHttp.getDevicesByUserId(this.userID)
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.devices = data;
      },
      error => {},
      () => {}
    );
}
```

***HTTP Service:***

```
public getDevicesByUserId(userID: number): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(this.url + 'api/device/user/' + userID, {
    headers: this.httpHeaders.getHeaders()
  })
  .map((response) => this.handleData(response))
  .catch((error) => this.handleError(error));
}
```

In the pattern above I am calling the subscribe method on the getDevicesByUserId function but in the http there is no observable being created. Maybe I am missing something but it is just a function returning the results of an http call. How am I able to call a subscribe method on a regular function like this? How does the function even have this property if I have not creating an observable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular 2 [Http service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/Http-class.html) functions for `get` and `post` are builtin to return a cold Observable which returns a response.

You do not have to explicitly create an Observable. You can go through the http code [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/http/src/http.ts) if you prefer.

Being a cold observable, the request itself is sent when an observer subscribes.
More on [hot and cold observable here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/16/cold-vs-hot-observables.html)
Your `getDevicesByUserId` in your own service returns the same observable which you finally subscribe to in the component.

Hope this clears it up.